# Insertar csrf-token de laravel en ajax

Tags: ajax, laravel

Esto en un `<script>` para enviar un formulario sin recargar la pagina pero me da el error HTTP419 por lo que lei es fallo del token, estuve viendo la documentación de laravel y la solución es esta:

**JS**:

```
 $.ajaxSetup({ headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') } });
```

Pero no consigo implementarla en el script..

**JS:**

```
<script>
    function loadLog() {
        var empresa= document.getElementById('empresa').value;
        var grupo= document.getElementById('grupo').value;
        var user_id= document.getElementById('user_id').value; 
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("createform").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
            }
        };

        xhttp.open("POST", "{{route('products.store')}}", true);
        xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xhttp.send("empresa="+empresa+"grupo="+grupo+"user_id="+user_id+"");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Con laravel no he trabajado, pero el token lo enviaría mediante `xhttp.setRequestHeader`.

Comment: el codigo que viste es jQuery,el que tienes en el loadLog() es JavaScript nativo agregalo de la siguiente forma:`xhttp.setRequestHeader("'X-CSRF-TOKEN", "tu_token");` o agrega `<meta content="{{ csrf_token() }}" name="X-CSRF-TOKEN" />`

Comment: he probado ambas y nada... no se que puede pasar..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

puedes hacerlo de varias formas:
la mejor forma siempre es enviarlo como dato:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" id="token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

o con jquery:

```
"_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}"   // directo con php
"_token": $('meta[name="csrf_token"]').attr('content') // obteniendo el valor
```

Comment: probé la opción 1 y nada la segunda no se como implementarlo

Comment: enviandola en tu arreglo de datots eje. datos={"_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}" } la opcion 1 es la mas simple ya que es un campo oculto que se envia junto con los datos de tu form que error te marca?

Comment: cambie a un nuevo script y use la opción 1 y perfecto gracias